# How to call a method in react's render method

Tags: reactjs

I got React nooob question.. The thing is that I need to call a method with the name `xxx`, in the `render` method but I don't know how.

This is the method:

```
xxx() {
    return (
        this.state.dataLoadedQuote &&
        <BlogBandLeadershipBlogQuoteItem item={this.state.blogQuote} labels={this.props.labels} />
    );
}
```

Comment: `this.xxx()` should work in most cases, unless you need to bind `this`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to make it clearer what you're trying to do.

Comment: I had tried in this way but the code refuse:

Comment: render (){
  return (
<div className="ms-u-sm6 ms-u-lg4 ms-u-xl3 column">
                                 {this.xxx(0)}
  )
}

Comment: This is the function:
 xxx() {
        return (
            this.state.dataLoadedQuote &&
            <BlogBandLeadershipBlogQuoteItem item={this.state.blogQuote} labels={this.props.labels} />
        );
    }

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling your `xxx()` function correctly (though you don't need to pass the argument `0` - it's unnecessary). The problem might be that, since you are using `this` inside `xxx()` you need to bind the function in your constructor. Otherwise, the `this` will not reference your component and so `this.state.dataLoadedQuote` will always be falsy.

So add:

```
this.xxx = this.xxx.bind(this);
```

Your constructor may now look something like:

```
constructor() {
  super();
  this.state = {}

  this.xxx = this.xxx.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: The constructor is inside in a class and the xxx propterty is an array. What should I do?  export default class myClass extends React.Component<aaa, bbb> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            xxx: [],